# Android PendingIntent howto

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Ok I am stuck. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I have no idea where to start with pendingintents. I need to start custom service that sends some data back to the activity that started it. How would I do that?

Comment: Cheers mates, you really saved me on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably register a Broadcast Receiver in my Activity and if I needed to communicate from Service to Activity, send a broadcast from the Service and the Activity's receiver would pick it up as long as the Activity was currently running. This, by the way, would not require the use of a PendingIntent. PendingIntents are more used with alarms from the AlarmManager or with Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using AsyncTask if you expect your Activity to be active (visible) all the time the Service runs.

Comment: Is this still compatible with the clients-server idea? I need anyone to be able to call this service.

Comment: Anyone can create AsyncTask object and execute it with the limitation that it has to be created and run on the main thread (UI thread). If this is not what you want then you will have to consider broadcast intents (with specific package name)